# Jquery event that fires when MVC controller is finished

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a jquery event that fires when an ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller is finished with it's work?

I have a link on an MVC page that allows the user to download a file.  The MVC controller returns a file.  When the link is clicked, I have a jquery function that locks the screen while the file is created.  The user then gets a dialogue to save the file.  But when the file is actually returned to the user, I have another jquery function that I want to run that unlocks the screen.

Here is my code:

In MVC view:

```
@Html.ImageLink("Download as CSV", "Report", "GetCSVFile", "", Url.Content("~/Content/images/csv.png"), "Generate Report", null, null, null, true, "blockscreenfunction")
```

In controller:

```
public ActionResult GetCSVFile ()
{
    string fullName = service.initiateCsvGeneration(1);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullName);
    return File(fullName, "text/csv", fileName);
}
```

So in summary, when the user starts the download, I lock the screen with the jquery blockscreenfunction function.  The controller then creates the file and the user gets the file download dialogue.  I have another jquery function that I use to unlock the screen.  How can I execute this function after the controller returns the file?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a useful feature.  Why do you want to lock the screen while they are downloading a file?  Have you seen this done somewhere else? Ultimately, I think the only way you can achieve what you are asking for is to do something like this `setTimeout(unblockscreenfunction, 3000)`

Comment: I actually agree with you, but the requirements are not set by me.  Maybe I could check with others and see if I can have this requirement changed.

Comment: If not, check this out http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try `@Ajax.ActionLink` instead. It has **OnComplete** property where you can set that jQuery function that unlocks the screen.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Download FIle", "ActionName", "ControllerName", ... ,  new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnBegin = "LockScreenFunction", OnComplete = "UnlockScreenFunction", UpdateTargetId = "TargetElement" })
```